# R library path for two Linux clusters

Tags: r, rstudio

I am working with two Linux clusters which share the same file system. 
Because of that, when I install libraries in one of the clusters, they
get installed in the same folder (/home/R), shared by both clusters, 
which causes conflicts if later I work on the other cluster.

Do you know if there is any external variable or even any R hidden config
I could use, so that, upon starting R (or Rstudio) on one cluster it could 
detect the cluster and the corresponding path for the libraries' location
(for instance /home/R/cluster1 and /home/R/cluster2)?

Thanks.

Comment: Not answering your question but I found R installed by anaconda on one cluster works fine on the other cluster.Therefore, you don't need two independent R installations or R library dirs unless you want to install different version of R or R lib.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it should be pretty straightforward. Create an `Rprofile.site` file (see the [Initialization at Startup](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/Startup.html) docs for where this goes). In that file, you can write R code to detect which cluster you're on.

Once you know which cluster you're on, use the `.libPaths()` function (see [libPaths docs](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.5.1/topics/libPaths)) to change the library path.

R will run the `Rprofile.site` file every time a new session starts up, so each session should get its library path adjusted appropriately for the cluster it's on.